# Model is a type, which is not valid in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to use a small model with my view as I learn ASP.MVC but I'm getting the error `'GalleryModel' is a type, which is not valid in the current context`.

This is my model assignment within my view:

```
@model = GalleryModel
```

The View is called within the controller:

```
    public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Gallery()
        {
            GalleryModel model = new GalleryModel() {
                ImageDirectories = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\MyFolder\")
            };
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

And the model is defined simply as:

```
namespace TestSite.Models.Gallery {
    public class GalleryModel {
        public string[] ImageDirectories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All the model should do is hold a list of strings that I pass into it and allow me to loop through them in the view to render partials (the strings will be file directories for images). In the view itself when viewed in Visual Studio the model `GalleryModel` is highlighted green to show it recognises it as a model but it won'use it, instead just showing the error mentioned above. I have gone in the view's web.config to add `<add namespace="TestSite.Models.Gallery"/>` to the `<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">` list of namespaces but that hasn't helped.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `=`: `@model GalleryModel`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't spot that. Thank you,Such a simple mistake I should have spotted it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it without '=':

```
@model GalleryModel
```

Comment: Don't answer typo questions. Instead flag them.

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].